# gradle clean jar fails because clean removes a directory that's needed later

Tags: gradle

I have a build.gradle with code like this:

```
task someDir(type: Exec) {
    outputs.files "someDir"
    mkdir "someDir"
}

jar {
    dependsOn "someDir"
    // needs to put someFile in someDir
    ...
}

clean << {
     project.delete "someDir"
}
```

When I run `gradle jar`, it works. When I run `gradle clean jar` it fails cause `someDir` does not exist. Looks almost like gradle is checking whether `someDir` exists only initially and not before running the target that actually depends on it. Why is that? How can I still run clean with other targets together? I like to rebuild everything before I commit my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this build script is that the `someDir` directory is created in the configuration phase, not when the `someDir` task runs. To fix this, wrap `mkdir "someDir"` with `doFirst { ... }` or `doLast { ... }`. It's also not clear why `someDir` has type `Exec`. Perhaps you didn't show the rest of its configuration?

Comment: The task is an Exec task because it not only creates said directory but also puts a properties file in the directory. I tried to make the example as small as possible but it looks like I removed too much. I want to create a properties file with build information from SVN, i.e., the build date, the `svnversion -n` output, and the SVN tag or branch, if any. I kind of had it working except for the combination of `gradle clean ...`

Comment: Then you just need to fix the Exec task by using `doFirst`, as I've described above.